# Error in using SharePoint Apps

Tags: sharepoint, dns, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm building a "Hello World" SharePoint app. I followed the following simple steps:

1. Logged-in with admin permissions to a server which has SharePoint installed on it.
2. Opened Visual Studio 2013 with admin permissions.
3. Selected File and then create new project. I selected 'App for SharePoint 2013' template, entered a project name and clicked OK.
4. I selected SharePoint hosted option and entered the following in the URL: http://ABC/sites/devtest/ (where ABC is the SharePoint server hostname)
5. I right-clicked the project and selected build and then selected deploy. It deployed successfully.

I opened the SharePoint site and navigated to Site contents. The URL is: http://ABC/sites/devtest/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx I found the SharePoint app and clicked on it. A new page opened with the following error:

> Description: Unable to locate the server named "app-8a64e85b517a50.ABC" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.

I didn't understand the error but I searched for it in google and tried to solve it by following the instruction of some articles but I couldn't resolve it yet. I followed the steps in this article: http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1954305/adding-dns-host-record-windows-server-2012-dns-server.html

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like either your DNS zone or sharepoint farm are not configured for addins. This documentation should help you do this [technet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the article and it is really difficult to follow. Do you have an idea why they're making so complicated to build sharepoint apps? I'm asking just because I feel that it cannot be that complicated... maybe i misunderstood something

Comment: The reason it is setup like that is for security reasons. If you want to save time on the infrastructure setup you can always spin a dev or trial office 365 tenant. Just keep in mind that the cloud version has more capabilities than on prem. Don't hesitate to mark my answer as answer, it will help people with the same question.

Comment: You suggested to "spin a dev or trial office 365 tenant". I my case, I'm not deploying this to production, I'm just trying to learn how to develop them. Do you know how can I prepare a dev environment easily?

Comment: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=403802&culture=en-US&country=US should allow you to start a trial. With that you'll already have most of the add-in infrastructure in place (just need to create an app catalog and/or a developer site)

Comment: Thanks for these details. That was helpful